# How to find out the the minimum value of the given integral?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

What is the value of

$min_{f\varepsilon D} \int_{0}^ {1} (1+x^2)f^2(x)dx$

where $D$={$f:[0,1] \to \mathbb R : f continuous,  \int_{0}^{1} f(x)dx =1$}

I have no idea how to look for minimum value?

First i just take $f=1$, value of integral comes out as $\frac{4}{3}$.

but how to proceed further?

Hint given is use Schwarz inequality

Comment: Scharwz inequality would be Cauchy-Schwarz inequality?

Comment: Hint: apply $CS$ to $\sqrt{1+x^2}f(x)$ and $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$

Comment: but i need $f^2$ in the integral

Comment: $f$ is continuous so belongs to $L^2$